# How i can click on link to get back to a previous page

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, phantomjs

I'm trying to get back to previous page by clicking on "Précédent" button
but, i didn't succeed, i tried many codes, all of the get me to the login page, that's mean i sign out,

in the page, if you perform a refesh or open it from another tab, it will disconnect and get you back to the login form

so, i recently figure it out how to use the same phantomjs session without disconnect but for one page, another page that i didn't scceed to access it without sign off, but there's a back button so, i want to use it to get back to the home page then enter the needed page

sorry for the confusion

the code

```
public void photoProfile() throws IOException {
  //   String locator = cssLocator;

    String cookie = String.join("\n",Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("temp\\cookie.txt")));

    Login webpage = new Login();
    WebDriver driver = dd.driver;
    driver.navigate().to("https://www4.inscription.tn/ORegMx/ListeInscriptions.jsp?Idsession="+cookie);
    WebElement back = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Précédent')]"));
    //back.click();
    //Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    //action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Précédent')]"))).click().perform();
    //action.moveToElement(back).perform();

    //Right Click
    //action.contextClick(back).perform();
    //Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    // builder.moveToElement(back).click(back);
     //builder.perform();
     System.out.println(driver.getTitle()); //to check if the page is the correct one
```

i tried

```
    WebElement back = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Précédent')]")).click;
```

but i'm getting

> type mismatch cannot convert from void to webelement

javascript of this button is

```js
javascript:history.back()
```

what i need to do?

Comment: Your code is pretty confusing. You should take a minute to clean it up and remove all the commented out code. If you want to show different attempts, separate them into different code blocks and make sure you put the specific problem/error associated with each attempt.

Comment: This message, `type mismatch cannot convert from void to webelement` doesn't correspond to the current code you have posted because the code won't compile because you are missing `()`s on your `.click()` line. That error is because you are trying to assign the return of `.click()` to a `WebElement` variable. `.click()` doesn't return anything (it returns `void)` so that's why you are getting that error. You need to either remove the variable and assignment or separate the assignment from the `.click()` line.

Comment: i solved the mystery by using .get to the full link that i find it using Burp, thanks for your time really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

It's returning that error because you're trying to call the .click(); method while setting a WebElement, and .click returns a void. You need to break it up into 2 commands:

```
WebElement back = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Précédent')]"));
back.click();
```

Comment: yes, i tried that too, when i use it, i think back do a reopening of the driver, that's why i got back to the login page

Answer (score 0):

I guess its because of the webpage security the session is getting expired and you are getting logged out when you are trying to go back after doing login, though if you are able to go back manually then you should be able to do it through automation as well. You are try the follow method to go back to the previous page:
`driver.navigate().back()`

Comment: the probem here is there's no previous page, just a button to get you to the previous page but if you opened the wbesite/link in chrome, you will not find the back arrow in the tob bar
but i fixed the problem, i .get directly to the link, i found it using Burp, that shows me the full link that have a sessionID, so, problem solved, thank you so much